# If real function $f$ is continuous and injective, is it strictly monotone?

Tags: real-analysis

> **Problem**
>
> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is continuous and injective. Prove (or disprove) that $f$ is a strictly monotone function.

I have tried to *prove* the monotonocity of $f$ for then by the injectivity of $f$ strict monotonicity will follow. However, I couldn't make any success.

I also tried to show that,

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is not a strictly monotone function. Then show that $f$ is either discontinuous or not injective.

In this case also I couldn't proceed beyond some trivial observations.

Can anyone help me to prove it?

Comment: Assume $f$ is continuous and not monotonic. Use the intermediate value theorem to show it is not injective.

Comment: @DanielFischer: What are possible cases I need to consider if $f$ is not monotonic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second statement is logically equivalent to the first. I advise you to prove the first one, and to prove it by showing that if $f$ not monotonic and is continuous, it is not injective.

You start with the fact that $f$ is not monotonic, meaning that there exists some series of three points $x_0<x_1<x_2$ such that either $f(x_0) < f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2) < f(x_1)$ or $f(x_0) > f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2) > f(x_1)$.

From there and from the fact that $f$ is continuous, you can prove it is not injective.